# When using open() it won't find the flag I'm trying to use

Tags: c, file, posix

I've been trying to work on this program to find the file size, and the way I'm going about it uses the open() function which requires a flag, but when I enter the correct flag it says it hasn't been declared yet. Here is the line and the imports I have.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>

int filedescriptor = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: The flags are in `<fcntl.h>`

Comment: `man open` is listing all of the required includes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. maybe `man 3 open` :-)

Comment: Man pages, man pages. MSVC says `<io.h>` is required for `open` but the flags are in `<fcntl.h>` as said above.

Comment: @Amadeus Actually I am using it a s google search string :P

Comment: @Amadeus sys calls are on 2, right?

Comment: @sidyll On my system it says: "POSIX Programmer's Manual" , on OPEN(3P). Of course on 2 too

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley that was it thank you!

Comment: @Amadeus may I ask, out of curiosity, on which system? If I'm not mistaken 3 usually was for library calls while 2 was for system ones (like open). I'm on macOS by the way.

Comment: @sidyll I'm using linux. Look at here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/open

Comment: Various systems have migrated various old system calls into chapter 3, since they're now backwards-compatibility wrappers around newer system calls.  Not sure that specifically explains why someone said to look for `open` in chapter 3, but bottom line, the distinction between chapters 2 and 3 grows ever more meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

You are missining `#include <fcntl.h>`

Note that in `man(3)` you are going to find POSIX specs, while in `man(2)` system specific implementations, if any.

In fact `man(3)` is the *POSIX Programmer's Manual* while `man(2)` is  *Linux Programmer's Manual*.

Note that this is not always true, but most of *POSIX* functions have also a `man(2)` page.